# Sorting Names and Reference IDs using XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

How to sort the names in alphabetical order? The reference IDs should also be exchanged based on the name sorting.

For Example:

**Input:**

```
<cross-refs id="c0065" refid="b0110 b0190 b0035">Loyal 2018; Anbu 1983; King 2022</cross-refs>
```

Name and Its ID

```
 **Name      --> ReferenceID**
Loyal 2018 --> b0110
Anbu 1983  --> b0190
king 2022  --> b0035
```

Expected Output:

```
<cross-refs id="c0065" refid="b0190 b0035 b0110">Anbu 1983; King 2022; Loyal 2018</cross-refs>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="cross-refs">
    <xsl:variable name="refids" select="tokenize(@refid, ' ')" />
    <xsl:variable name="names" select="tokenize(., '; ')" />
    <xsl:variable name="refs">
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to count($refids)">
            <ref refid="{$refids[current()]}" name="{$names[current()]}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="sorted-refs">
        <xsl:perform-sort select="$refs/ref">
            <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
        </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- to output: -->
    <cross-refs id="{@id}" refid="{$sorted-refs/ref/@refid}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$sorted-refs/ref/@name" separator="; "/>
    </cross-refs>
</xsl:template>
```

I wonder if anyone can come up with a shorter way.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3 (supported by current versions of Saxon Java, .NET, C, JS as well as Altova) you could use

```
<xsl:template match="cross-refs">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="ref-map" select="for-each-pair(tokenize(@refid, '\s+'), tokenize(., ';\s*'), function($ref, $name) { map { 'ref' : $ref, 'name' : $name } }) => sort((), function($m) { $m?name })"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@id"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="refid" select="$ref-map ! ?ref"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$ref-map ! ?name" separator="; "/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

which can be shortened to

```
<xsl:template match="cross-refs">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="ref-map" select="for-each-pair(tokenize(@refid, '\s+'), tokenize(., ';\s*'), function($ref, $name) { map { 'ref' : $ref, 'name' : $name } }) => sort((), function($m) { $m?name })"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@id"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="refid" select="$ref-map?ref"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$ref-map?name" separator="; "/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score -1):

XSLT xsl:sort

The xsl:sort element is used to sort the output. Note: xsl:sort is always within xsl:for-each or xsl:apply-templates.

Comment: I think you're underestimating the difficulty of this problem. Of course xsl:sort is used for sorting. But you're not showing how to use xsl:sort on the provided input in order to produce the expected output.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).